# Can't inject dependencies in Spring Security configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a spring project using Spring Security. I want to inject dependencies into my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extending class but the dependencies do not seem to be getting injected. My controllers also use dependency injection and it does work there.

My SecSecurity class:

```
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;
    LogoutSuccessHandler handler = new LogoutSuccess();



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());


    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
              http.   logout().and().
                      httpBasic()
                      .and()
                      .authorizeRequests()
                      .antMatchers( "/", "/home", "/user", "/vestigingen", "/available", "/logout").permitAll()
                      .anyRequest().authenticated()
                      .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(handler).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false).permitAll()
                      .and().csrf()
                      .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());


    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserPrincipalDetailsService();
    }



    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userPrincipalDetailsService);


        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

It cannot find beans for the userPrincipalDetailsService class.

UserPrincipalDetailService class:

```
@Component
public class UserPrincipalDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepositorySQL userRepository = new UserRepositorySQL();

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(s);

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(user);

        return userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

to clarify: I can't inject any dependencies within my SecSecurityConfig class eventhough i have tried annotating it in many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Define the bean name @Component("userPrincipalDetailsService") in the UserPrincipalDetailsService class.

```
@Component("userPrincipalDetailsService")
public class UserPrincipalDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepositorySQL userRepository = new UserRepositorySQL();

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(s);

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(user);

        return userPrincipal;
    }
}
```